# Hide an item on all pages where id parameter in URL greater than some number

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        if (typeof jQuery === 'function') {
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                if (document.URL.indexOf('http://test.com/browse/ID-2007') === 0) {
                    jQuery('#test').hide();
                }
            });
    }
    } catch(err) {}
</script>
```

How to fix the script so that `jQuery('#test').Hide();` performed wherever `ID > 2007`

Comment: can use double equals to,indexOf returns int,you dont need a type comparator perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the part of the URL leading up to the ID is always the same, you could just remove that part, parse the remaining part into a number and check it:

```
var id = parseInt(document.URL.replace('http://test.com/browse/ID-', ''), 10);

if (id > 2007) {
   // Do your thing
}
```

If more complex matching is needed, the [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method can take a regular expression to use for matching as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlchunks = window.location.href.split('/');
var id = urlchunks[urlchunks.length-1].split('-');
if(parseInt(id[1]) > 2007) {
        jQuery('#test').hide();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JavaScript Regex for find your id :

```
var regex = new RegExp("ID-([\d]+)", "g");
var id = regex.exec(document.URL);
if (id[1] > 2007) jQuery('#test').hide();
```